# BeforeinstallPromt event fired still Add to home screen Prompt not working after setting any value in window.location

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

Add to Home Screen feature of google is not working after setting any value in window.location.

What has been done so far?

Refer : web-fundamentals-app-install-banners

During this implementation I am capturing the `'beforeInstallPromptEvent'` of window and using it later whenever required.

PFB the Code Snippet for the same:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  deferredPrompt = e;
  // Update UI notify the user they can add to home screen
  showInstallPromotion();
});


btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
  btnAdd.style.display = 'none';
  // Show the prompt
  deferredPrompt.prompt();
  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
  deferredPrompt.userChoice
    .then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
});
```

This above code works perfectly in normal journey but it stopworking as soon as I include something in window.location to go to some app which in install in the device,

When the below code for Truecaller functionality is added in tandem with Add to Home Screen, it stops working:

```
window.location='xxxxxsdk://some-url/';
```

I have also tried with other options to redirect to app like `location.assign()` but still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi) try to put it after the app is installed:

```
window.addEventListener('appinstalled', function() {
  // window.location = ...
});
```

Here is the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/appinstalled_event